# gst-inspect-1.0 fails with "g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed" if gstreamer-1.16 is built as static libs

Tags: static, gstreamer-1.0

I have built gstreamer-1.16 and its plugins (base, good, bad and ugly) with `--enable-static --disable-shared --enable-static-plugins` options. Looks like the build has succeeded but when I run `./gst-inspect-1.0` (from my custom build directory) I get the following errors:

```
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(gst-plugin-scanner:2271): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:48:43.035: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
```

And gst-inspect hangs.
What did I miss?